# Properties file not found in jar

Tags: java, properties-file

This is my code to read .properties file in my project.

```
public class Configuration {

    private static JSONObject readConfigFile(File filename) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject configProperties = new JSONObject();
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {

            input = new FileInputStream(filename);

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

            // get the property value and print it out


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return configProperties;

    }

    public static JSONObject loadConfigurationDetails(String configFilePath) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject configurationDetails = new JSONObject();

        File configFile = new File(configFilePath);

        if(configFile.exists()){
            configurationDetails = readConfigFile(configFile);
        }else{
            System.out.println("configuration.properties file not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return configurationDetails;
    }

    public static JSONObject loadConfigurationDetails() throws JSONException {

        String configFilePath = "configuration.properties";

        JSONObject loadConfigurationDetails = loadConfigurationDetails(configFilePath);

        return loadConfigurationDetails;
    }
}
```

The following is my Project Structure
projectname
    -src
    -target
    -properties file
    -pom.xml

You can view my project structure :[link](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/salman-delete/Capture.PNG)

My Properties file is under the root project.
I am not able to read this file when I build jar file and run it.
I am getting file not found for the properties file.

Inside my Main method I am calling my method as follows:

```
JSONObject loadConfigurationDetails = Configuration.loadConfigurationDetails();
```

**Modified code and error**

```
public class Configuration {

  public static JSONObject loadConfigurationDetails() throws JSONException {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String filePath = "";
        JSONObject configProperties = new JSONObject();
    try {

      InputStream inputStream = 
        Configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("configuration.properties");

      prop.load(inputStream);
      configProperties.put("URL",prop.getProperty("URL",""));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return configProperties;

  }

}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at com.demo.main.Configuration.loadConfigurationDetails(Configuration.java:33)
    at com.demo.main.Run.main(Run.java:30)
```

Comment: Resources are not files and cannot be accessed with `FileInputStream` or its cognates. You should be using `Class.getResource()` and friends.

Comment: Please have a look at my modified code and my project structure.
In my modified code I am getting null pointer exception because file is not found.
Please see my project structure.
Thanks for your response.

Comment: I have used the code provided by Alan Hay Sir in the link by mkyong

Answer (score 1):

You need to read it from the classpath. So, assuming it is in the root of the JAR (which it would be under a standard Maven project layout of src/main/resources/my.props):

```
input = Configuration.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Comment: This error I get if I use the above method :non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.
because my functions are static.
If I remove static keyword from my functions this will work.
But I won't be able to call my method in the main method.It will also give me the same error.

Comment: Sir I have edited my Question and posted the null pointer which I am facing now.
Thanks for your response.

Comment: When I see my configuration file in netbeans File window options , I see at  the src and  target level.
I mean scr,target,pom.xml and file are at same level.

Comment: You can view my project structure :[link](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/salman-delete/Capture.PNG)

Comment: where to put the prop file in simple java project